# Do I have to manually parse the document to show SignatureHelp?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm creating an extension to add support for a custom language on VS Code and I'm struggling on providing Signature Help because I can't seem to find a way to tell what signature I should show the user unless I manually parse the entire document to find out what is expected.

My question is, does VS Code API provides some way for me to tell the function/etc where the user is when the provider is invoked or do I have to parse the document manually so I can find it by myself?

I'm using the "direct implementation" way (without language servers), if that matters.

I hope my question is clear, thanks in advance.

Comment: How would VSCode even know what a function _is_ in your custom language?

Comment: I was thinking about that too.. but was hoping it could use the tokens used for highlight or something like that, guess I was wrong

Comment: Yeah, I don't think that's possible.